# Can't understand compiler's behaviour (creating object)

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(){ std::cout << "created" << std::endl; }
    A(A& other) { std::cout << "copied" << std::endl; }
    A& get(){ std::cout <<"got" << std::endl; return *this; }
    ~A(){ std::cout << "destroyed" << std::endl; }
};
```

Now, lines

```
A a = A().get();
```

and

```
A a;    
a = A();
```

compile and work correctly, but

```
A a = A();
```

claims:

```
no matching function for call to ‘A::A(A)’
note: candidates are: A::A(A&)
note:                 A::A()
```

And to make things explicit,

```
A a = (A&)A();
```

claims:

```
error: invalid cast of an rvalue expression of type ‘A’ to type ‘A&’
```

I completely don't understand this behaviour.

P.S. I know, that if I make `const` reference in copy c_tor, everything will be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A a = A();
```

This line tries to call the copy-constructor passing a temporary object, and the copy-constructor takes argument by non-const reference. But a temporary object cannot be bound to a non-const reference. That is why you get the compilation error.

However, a temporary object can be bound to `const` reference. So, the solution is to make the parameter `const` reference as:

```
A(const A& other) { std::cout << "copied" << std::endl; }
```

Comment: this explanation sounds most logical for me

Answer (score 3):

The copy constructor should get its argument as a `const` reference (or a simple `A` value). In your current setup, the program would have to make a mutable reference to a temporary, which is invalid.

Comment: You know, g++ does not think so sometimes. For exasmple, private member of type `std::auto_ptr<std::string>` will make g++ create default copy c_tor with non-const reference

Comment: @Lol4t0: It is OK to have a copy ctor taking a non-const reference; the problem arrives when you try to use it with something that cannot be converted into a non-const ref, such as in this example.

Answer (score 3):

This is simple: a rvalue (i.e. something that must be on the right hand side of an equal sign), can convert to a constant reference or be copied. Only a lvalue (i.e. something that can be placed on the left of an equal sign) can be converted into a non-constant reference. The reason being that you may be tempted to modify the content of the non-constant reference, which would be invalid.

`A()` is  a rvalue, and therefore cannot be converted into a non-constant reference. This is your error.

Comment: Ok,but why c_tor return r-value? I can call members of that r-value, and I can even write A() = A(); :) More, why does my get() function work? And If you look output, you can see, that no object is removed twice

Comment: Oh,It seems also, that r-value _can_be_ l-value